# Add object debug visualization?

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I add a debug visualizer to my class, so this visualization text will be shown in the Object Inspector for all objects of this type?
For example, it should show this debugging visualization for every instance of my type in an array or a list of object's properties. (in a way like VS does)

Comment: Is that not what `toString()` is for ? Or are you asking something else ?

Comment: @Deepak Bala, I have toString defined, but the object inspector shows only type name and some "id".

Comment: The `toString()` of the object is invoked in the inspector view that is triggered using the `Ctrl + Shift + I` shortcut. Can you update your post with the class's `toString()` method and what it looks like on the inspector ? It should work out of the box.

Comment: @Deepak Bala, it shows this toString value in a bottom panel for an object selected. What I need to is to show this for *every* object of my type in an array or a list of properties. (in a way like VS does)

Comment: You'd like to see the `toString()` value of all your object's instances ? Eclipse has a feature that does this. Click on the variable of interest under the `Variables` tab. Then select the option `All Instances`. That shows you a [visualization of all instances of a particular type](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fshared%2Fref-allinstances.htm). Is that what you want ?

Comment: @Deepak Bala, cool feature but not what I need. And what I need is to inspect objects of my program, and whenever an instance of my type appears - it should be visualized as my "debug text". You can take a look at VS debug visualizers for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Debug Visualisation View](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/debugvisualisation/).